# Checkout Issue in a Flutter based Food Delivery App

Tags: flutter, debugging, server-side, payment-processing

I am encountering a challenge with a Flutter-based food delivery app developed by my partner.

1. The issue arises when a user selects "online payment" as their preferred option and proceeds to click "check-out." Surprisingly, the order is being placed without the required payment processing.
2. When a user proceeds to click check-out, users receive no immediate response, and unbeknownst to them, the order is being placed. This lack of feedback leads to users repeatedly clicking "checkout," resulting in multiple unintended orders. It's important to note that this occurrence is intermittent.

I am seeking insights into potential solutions or debugging steps to address this error. Any guidance or recommendations from experienced developers would be greatly appreciated.

My partner attempted to address the issue of multiple orders by initiating server restarts. While this approach appears effective intermittently, it does not provide a consistent resolution.

Comment: With the currently provided information there is no real way to help. You need to focus your question on a *specific* issue and provide a way to reproduce it in a way of a code snippet.